# How to run several correlations tests in R and create a new table out of results from function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, subset, correlation

I have a df that looks like this image here.

[Current df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppXqJ.png)

I would like to run a correlation test between `value_x` and `value_y` where the day value is distinct and its a specific fruit.

So it would test between `value_x` and `value_y` where fruit is `"Apple"` and day is `1` The function should however take all occurrences of `value_x` and `value_y`.

Where fruit is distinct and day is unique.

So, the correlation test would look like, `value_x`,`value_y` if `fruit == "apple"` and grouped by day.

So it would take values .34 and .14, 0.23 and 0.68, 0.05 and 2.12 for the correlation test.

I would then like to present this data in a new df

[new data frame (desired output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efsrl.png)

dput

```
structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),

           Value_x = c(0.34, 0.32, 0.23, 0.32, 0.23, 0.14, 0.05, -0.04, 0.05, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04),

           Value_y = c(0.14, 0.05, -0.04, 0.32, 0.68, 1.04, 1.4, 1.76, 2.12, 2.48, 2.84, 3.2),

           Fruit = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L),

                             .Label = c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",

      row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I'm quite a beginner at R still and this function is really over my head. I have used cor() for correlation tests in the past. I do not quite know where to begin with this problem. Would really appreciate any tips.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please add the `dput` of example input

Comment: Sure, on it now!

Comment: added it now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `group_by` `cor`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Fruit) %>%
    summarise(out = cor(Value_x, Value_y))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(out = cor(Value_x, Value_y)), by = Fruit]
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks so much. I had imagined it to be way more lines of code! :) Thank you!! :)) I never knew cor functions could be added in to group by. Learned something new.